# How to find the general solution of $yy^{''}-(y')^2=y^2lny$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

first I tried :

$y'=p$

$y''=p\frac{dp}{dy}$

$yp\frac{dp}{dy}-p^2=y^2lny$

$w=p^2$

$\frac{dw}{dy}-\frac{2w}y=2y^2lny$

$wy^{-2}=2\int lnydy$

$p^2=2y+cy^2$

secondly

$\frac{yy''-(y')^2}{y^2}=lny$

$d(\frac{y'}{y})=d(xlny+c)$

$\frac{y'}{y}=xlny+c$

and lastly

$\frac{y''}{y'}-\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{ylny}{y'}$

$lny'-lny=\int\frac{ylny}{y'}$

Comment: $$\log y=\frac{yy''-(y')^2}{y^2}=\left(\frac{y'}y\right)'=(\log y)''\implies\log y(x)=A\cdot\mbox{___}+B\cdot\mbox{___}$$

Comment: @Did I see a lot of good comments from you lately. Have you stopped answering questions? (I feel some of them could fit as answers, actually)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$yy^{''}-(y')^2=y^2ln(y)$$
$$\frac{yy^{''}-(y')^2}{y^2}=ln(y)$$
$$(\frac{y'}{y})'=ln(y)$$
$$(ln(y))''=ln(y)$$
Substitute $z=ln(y)$
$$z''=z$$
Therefore
$$z=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}$$

and we get
$$y=e^z=exp(c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x})$$

Answer (score 0):

$$yy''-y'^2=y^2\ln(y)$$
$$\frac{y''}{y^2}-\frac{y'^2}{y^2}=\ln y$$
$$\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)'=ln(y)$$
Let $y=e^f$ , then $y'=yf'$ and $\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)=f'$
$$\left(\frac{y'}{y}\right)'=f''=\ln(y)=f$$
$$f(x)=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}$$
$$y(x)=e^{c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}}$$

Comment: Thanks but it is the same solution with which Did hinted and uri goren answered.  Care to solve different way?  :)